# python pygtk webview rendering downloaded html code

Tags: python, webkit, pygtk, pycurl

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO
import gtk
import webkit

wd = gtk.Window()
wd.set_title("example browser")

storage = StringIO()
c=pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.ENCODING,"")
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION,1)
c.setopt(pycurl.AUTOREFERER,1)
c.setopt(pycurl.HEADER,1)
c.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS,5)
c.setopt(pycurl.FAILONERROR,1)
c.setopt(pycurl.URL,"http://whatsmyua.com")
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, storage.write)
c.perform()
c.close()

html1 = storage.getvalue()
htm = webkit.WebView()

htm.load_string("<p>example page</p><br>" , "text/html" , "utf-8" , html1)

wd.add(htm)
wd.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

above code downloads the page and then shows a window containing only "example page" string and nothing else. So what should I do . please help......

Comment: Why use `pycurl`? That's about as easy to use as using a bench-mounted grinding stone to polish your shoes; you are just as likely to get hurt..

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to call it like this:

```
htm.load_string(html1, 'text/html', 'utf-8', 'file://')
```

The last parameter is the base URI for relative links in the document.